# Paypal recurring payment profile API

Tags: wordpress, paypal

I'm trying to create a recurring payment profile using paypal API in Wordpress. After taking the required information from the user I'm making a request using the following url.

```
https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/USER=xylon-facilitator_api1.sjinnovation.com&PWD=9GDLFHDX3TQYWX4F&SIGNATURE=AO0B8EcgGN1ir1vqHVNLJ4fmaGxoAbfv5uwkwVkBxkD8vVif33kMJlD0&METHOD=CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile&CREDITCARDTYPE=Visa&ACCT=4311196648584326&EXPDATE=122019&FIRSTNAME=Xylon&LASTNAME=Gracias&PROFILESTARTDATE=2014-12-29T12:14:38Z&BILLINGPERIOD=Month&BILLINGFREQUENCY=1&AMT=20
```

But for the response i get following data

```
Array ( [headers] => Array ( [date] => Mon, 29 Dec 2014 12:14:39 GMT [server] => Apache [content-length] => 445 [connection] => close [content-type] => text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 ) [body] =>
Not Found

The requested URL /cgi-bin/ppapi was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
Apache Server at api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com Port 443
[response] => Array ( [code] => 404 [message] => Not Found ) [cookies] => Array ( ) [filename] => )
```

I'm using following link for reference

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-pro/integration-guide/WPRecurringPayments/

I'm Using direct payement method

Answer (score 0):

Look at the API reference documentation here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/#merchant

... and then some of the many examples out on the web. As a 404 usually indicates, you have an incorrect URL (you probably meant to post to https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp if you are using the signature authentication and NVP; you omitted the path "nvp") and there are further issues after that with your variable handling.

Comment: the URL will be like this?? 
api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp?....... Can you point out some of my mistakes in variable handling?